# How to convert a unicode list of tuples into utf-8 with python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

My function returns a tuple
which is then assigned to a variable x and appended to a list.

```
x = (u'string1', u'string2', u'string3', u'string4')
resultsList.append(x)
```

The function is called multiple times and final list consists of 20 tuples.

The strings within the tuple are in unicode and I would like to convert them to utf-8.

Some of the strings include also non-ASCII characters like ö, ä, etc.

Is there a way to convert them all in one step?

Comment: sorry that was just a typo...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714750/encoding-a-list-of-tuples-with-python/39576652#39576652

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a nested list comprehension:

```
encoded = [[s.encode('utf8') for s in t] for t in resultsList]
```

This produces a list of lists containing byte strings of UTF-8 encoded data.

If you were to print these lists, you'll see Python represent the contents of the Python byte strings as Python literal strings; with quotes and with any bytes that aro not printable ASCII  codepoints represented with escape sequences:

```
>>> l = ['Kaiserstra\xc3\x9fe']
>>> l
['Kaiserstra\xc3\x9fe']
>>> l[0]
'Kaiserstra\xc3\x9fe'
>>> print l[0]
Kaiserstraße
```

This is **normal** as Python presents this data for debugging purposes. The `\xc3` and `\x9f` escape sequences represent the two UTF-8 bytes C39F (hexadecimal) that are used to encode the small ringel-es character.

Comment: Thank you very much, but what about the non-ASCII characters Kaiserstraße becomes Kaiserstra\xc3\x9fe

Comment: @user2560609: This works on *unicode* values, any such value, including non-ASCII codepoints. Your output is a Python string literal representation of a UTF8 encoded bytestring.

Comment: @user2560609: In other words: it works. `'\xc3\x9f'` is Python's escape format to represent the two hexadecimal bytes C3 and 9F, which is the UTF-8 representation of the `ß` small ringel-es.